# adb backup gives "Bus error: 10"

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb

I have just installed the latest version of the Android Studio. I now have adb and fastboot available through the platform-tools.

When I run `adb backup -all` I get a "Bus error: 10".

What's wrong here? Is there a problem with the lastest version of the Android Studio?

FYI, I am running on Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.4), rooted Android v4.4.4.

Cheers!